# Does construct a new object cause Memory leak

Tags: c#

Does this method use plenty of my memory resources?

```
Private MyWorkerClass worker;
Private Thread myWorkerThread;
//private Thread  myWorkerThread= new Thread(worker.doThisWork); // i cant do this, because i cant restart the thread when i construct it here.
public void IwantMyWorkDosomething(){
    myWorkerThread= new Thread(worker.doThisWork);
    myWorkerThread.start();
    myWorkerThread.stopWorking(); // stop my worker class thread running;
}
public void main(){

    this.IwantMyWorkDosomething();
    this.IwantMyWorkDosomething();
    this.IwantMyWorkDosomething();
    this.IwantMyWorkDosomething();
    this.IwantMyWorkDosomething();

}
```

my Code is working, but i am not sure whether it gonna crash my program if i run the method 1000 times.

Comment: *Does this loop use plenty of my memory rescourse?* Only the strings that are allocated to display the compiler errors.

Comment: Read about garbage collector.

Comment: this is the most silly bit of code i've seen in a while ... what are you trying to do or achieve with it ?

Comment: because if i cant restart the same thread that i stopped when i using the old myWorkerThread, so i decide to construct it again before i start it.

Comment: You really need to reconsider what that code is doing.  Its all kinds of messed up.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  I dont get it. I am new to coding. Having a hard time to understand how memory assigned and reused.

Comment: Have you even tried running this code?

Comment: @kendallFrey not yet for 1000 times, but i dun wanna crash my computer lol

Comment: myWorkerThread= new Thread(worker.doThisWork); does this gonna allocate new memory to my program?

Comment: If you are a beginner, then you should not use threads. At all. Make sure you're competent to write a single-threaded program before you write a multi-threaded program.

Comment: @zhihuagao: you can't crash your computer with such code. The days were a simple program bought the whole computer down are long gone. Your app might and will crash during development, but that has no side effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing a thread object is cheap. Also, re-constructing a new one is cheap. The garbage collector will free the unused resources, you just need to make sure you're not unnessecarilly keeping references to finished thread objects.

What could become a resource problem is only when you try to run thousands of threads *at the same time*. But even then, it's not the memory that will usually cause the bottleneck but the CPU and the task scheduler (i.e the tasks will start to run slower than exected).